# Using Automator/Applescript to create a list of file paths

Tags: applescript, automator

I am looking for a way to look through a list of thousands of file names, search for them within a certain set of subfolders on a server and to export a list of those files locations.

Example:
Saved in Textedit or Excel I have:

**12345.psd**

**67890.psd**

These need to be searched for here:

**Servername:Image Bank:Photography:**

I then need a list of the locations of these files exported into TextEdit or Excel to get a list such as:

**Servername:Image Bank:Photography:Theme name:12345.psd**

**Servername:Image Bank:Photography:Theme name:67890.psd**

Manually searching for individual files is taking an age. I am new to both Automator and Applescript, so am learning on the fly. So far I have scoured forums and tutorials, gone through it with friends, colleagues and IT and spent hours testing and trialing with no success.

Does this at least sound possible? If so, I will continue trying as this will be invaluable in future projects.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service! You should show us the code that's not working for you. Have a look at, [How to create a Minimal, Complete,and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help fix your code that's not working for you. Note that while I understand you said "I am new to both Automator and Applescript ..." you still need to do something other then just asking for a solution to something that you have not show any effort in doing it for yourself first. You might actually be better of using a `bash` _script_ with the `find` _command_.

Comment: Apologies. I don't think I explained myself in enough detail and was pointed here by someone without really knowing much about it.
I don’t want any code writing for me, really I’d like to know if what I am asking is possible. I’ve spent the day using tutorials and scouring forums to try and find some way of getting this to work, mainly using Automator, with no success. I was hoping someone could confirm it sounds possible to do, if so I would keep going as having a script that does the job will help loads in the future on other jobs.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, Automator could be used to accomplish a task such as you've outlined (although it really depends on missing information in your question), however IMO it may not the best suited tool to do the job. A `bash` _script_ might be much more efficient. Is `Image Bank` a mounted share of `Servername`? In other words, is it accessible as `/Volumes/Image Bank`? Can the path filenames be POSIX path filenames instead, e.g. `/path/to/file.psd` vs. `path:to:file.psd`?

Comment: Here are some other issues I see with your question. You said "Example: Saved in Textedit or Excel I have:", now what format are these files? Is the TextEdit saved as its default Rich Text or as Plain Text? Is the Excel file saved as an Excel document, e.g. .xls, .xlsx or as a Text CSV (.csv) file? Also, are the filenames all numeric and only a `.psd` extension or alphanumeric and other extensions as well? How many filenames are in the file(s)? (Why two different Apps, choose one and one format type and stick with it to get the job done!)

Comment: For example, if the target filenames were all numeric with `.psd` ext and `Image Bank` was a mounted share, as `/Volumes/Image Bank`, and POSIX path filename was acceptable, then the following _command_ would generate a path filename list of all numeric named .psd files at the searched location, which you can then use additional _commands_ to narrow down the list to just those matching in the other list. `find -E /Volumes/Image\ Bank/Photography -type f  -iregex '.*[0-9]{1,}\.psd' > All_Numeric_PSD_Filenames.txt` Once you have the targeted list, it can be further formatted to meed the needs.

Comment: In other words, it will be faster to create a temporary list of all the path filenames that match a given criteria and further process that list to end up with a list of the path filenames of the filenames in the TextEdit/Excel list. IMO It is going to be much faster all done in, e.g. `bash` then in an Automator workflow using multiple other _actions_ to accomplish the same end result. The finale list can be in either form, i.e. `/path/to/file.psd` or `path:to:file.psd`, it just depends on what you're going got do with the final list.

Comment: Image Bank is a folder on our server, with numerous theme folders within it, each containing PSD files, usually all named as numerical product codes, but occasionally with letters as well. The path can be expressed using either you suggested. I am supplied a list of filenames in a .xls spreadsheet, I can then save that as .xlsx, csv or a textedit file, any are fine, the same with a TextEdit file. I mentioned both file types in case it was perhaps possible with one but not the other. The supplied spreadsheet currently contains 3100 product codes.

Comment: So from what you have mentioned, you think it would be faster to create a list of File Paths for all the base.psd files with the Image Bank folder and then further filter this list down. I can see this working easier with an Excel file as I could use the additional columns to make the filtering easier.

Comment: Because what I want to say is far to long to put into comments, I'm just going to post an answer that will show exactly what I'd do if tasked to create a list of fully qualified path filenames of PSD files on the server at a given location based on a list containing only the filename and extension of the target PSD files.

Answer (score 0):

As an example and test...

I created a hierarchical folder structure at 'Servername:Image Bank:Photography' containing three 'Theme name' folders which between them contains 90,000 .psd files (30,000 files in each 'Theme name' folder).

I then created a list of 3,100 .psd filenames. This list contains only the filename and .psd extension and the filenames are spread out over the names of the 90,000 .psd files created for this test so as to have to progressively read through the entire master list, as necessary, that gets created to get the fully qualified path filenames.

I then wrote this `bash` *script* in Terminal:

```
touch getpfn
nano getpfn
```

In `nano` I typed the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

master_list="The_PSD_Path_Filenames_List_on_Servername_at_Image_Bank_Photography.txt"
get_list="The_Get_Path_Filenames_List.txt"
the_list="The_Wanted_Path_Filenames_List.txt"

psd_file_path='/Volumes/Image Bank/Photography'

find "$psd_file_path" -type f -iname '*.psd' > "$master_list"

while read -r line; do
    grep -m 1 "$line" "$master_list" >> "$the_list"
done<"$get_list"
```

Saved the changes and exited `nano` by pressing the following key sequences: 
<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>
<kbd>Y</kbd>
<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Back in Terminal:

Made the *script* executable:

```
chmod u+x getpfn
```

Executed the *script*:

```
 ./getpfn
```

On my system it took under six minutes to get the 3,100 fully qualified path filenames of PSD files on the server against the list of 90,000 entries. Understandably so, YMWV based on all the relevant factors!

I have included a commented version of this `bash` *script* below:

```
#!/bin/bash

    # Define Variables

        # These filenames are arbitrary but should adequately 
        # differentiate their functionality within this script.
        # Set them to whatever is appropriate for your usage.

        # 'master_list' gets created by the output of the 'find'
        # command. It will contain the fully qualified path filenames
        # of all PSD files within Servername:Image Bank:Photography
        # mounted at '/Volumes/Image Bank' using: 'psd_file_path'

master_list="The_PSD_Path_Filenames_List_on_Servername_at_Image_Bank_Photography.txt"

    # 'get_list' Is a plain text file created from the spreadsheet.
    # It contains one filename, e.g. 12345.psd, per line. Filenames
    # can be numeric and or alphanumeric, doesn't matter as long as
    # there is only one filename per line and is a plain text file.

get_list="The_Get_Path_Filenames_List.txt"

    # 'the_list' gets created by the output of the 'grep' command.
    # Each line of 'master_list' that contains the filename on
    # the processed line of the 'get_list' is written to 'the_list'
    # 'the_list' then contains the fully qualified pathnames
    # of the filenames in 'get_list' based on 'psd_file_path'.

the_list="The_Wanted_Path_Filenames_List.txt"

    # Note: This script assumes that 'Image Bank' is the mounted share
    # of 'Servername' and is accessible at: '/Volumes/Image Bank'

psd_file_path='/Volumes/Image Bank/Photography'

    # Create the Master PSD Path Filename List

find "$psd_file_path" -type f -iname '*.psd' > "$master_list"

    # Loop through the e.g. 'Get_Path_Filenames_List.txt' against the e.g.
    # 'The_PSD_Path_Filenames_List_on_Servername_at_Image_Bank_Photography.txt'
    # while writing matches to e.g: The_Wanted_Path_Filenames_List.txt

while read -r line; do
    grep -m 1 "$line" "$master_list" >> "$the_list"
done<"$get_list"

    # Now finished, the e.g. 'The_Wanted_Path_Filenames_List.txt' file
    # contains the mounted path filenames of all the filenames in 
    # the e.g. 'Get_Path_Filenames_List.txt' file.
    #
    # Depending on what will be done with this list, further
    # processing can be done as needed and or wanted.
```